# how to put a record on top of list in list view based on a certain user profile, can I use apex to filter a listview? salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex, salesforce-lightning

How should I filter a list view of a custom object, if I want a certain user to see the list of records on top of the list view depending on the status of the picklist field for ex. the status is Ready then it will be on the top of the list if the user is for ex. Sales Executive. any ideas on how to do this? can I use apex to filter a listview?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **List View filters** for status and Sharing Setting Feature provided in the standard listview, and choose the option **Share list view with groups of users** where you can have the option to choose multiple

1. Public groups or
2. Roles or
3. Roles and Subordinates
   You can use any of them or all of them.

But if the constraint of your problem is not applicable to the standard way then I suggest you can create a custom list view with help of Apex and Aura Component List view or Lightning Web Component List view.

Let me know if it helps you out or not.

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, I will try to create a LWC for this. - I think there is still no lightning-list-view available now.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try to do it without any code. Make a formula field (type = number, name = Sort Order?) and do whatever you need in that field. You can reference other fields on the record but also things like `$Profile.Name`. It'd still be user's job to sort by this field but you know... you can lead the horse to water but you can't make it drink ;)

Another way would be some Einstein scoring stuff, like all the demos where they're rating hot leads, opportunities most likely to close?

Have you considered making a report + dashboard? They'd see nice chart of top 10 records and they could drill down to a report where you control the sorting.

If you really feel need to code something... Yes, Apex would be able to pull up to 10K records from a listview, you need to read up about [StandardSetController](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.224.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_pages_standardsetcontroller.htm) and setFilterId. But it'll really be limited to first 10K and then you apply your sorting/filtering on top of that. If there's important record after this 10K you might miss it.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I am considering making a data table and filter it their. I also have one more question, if you know how please help me here is the link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73191364/lightning-record-view-form-is-not-displaying-the-record-with-the-id-that-is-fetc)